# How to avoid "ALREADY EXISTS" Mutation while writing Mutation to Spanner Table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-dynamodb, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I have a certain use-case, where I'm trying to write around TB's of data in Spanner. We are extracting that data from DynamoDb and exporting that data in bzip2 format in Google Cloud Storage. So Basically we have primary id's in Spanner and we have to ignore already exist rows in Spanner. So I have written the below code to achieve the same.

```
    Mutation.WriteBuilder mutation = Mutation.newInsertBuilder(spannerTable.get());
```

I have written insert builder as I don't want to update the existing row in Spanner. Using the below code to write row to Spanner by setting FailureMode.

```
results2.apply("Write Mutations to Spanner",SpannerIO.write()
                .withInstanceId(spannerInstanceId)
                .withDatabaseId(spannerDatabaseId)
                //.withBatchSizeBytes(2000000)
                //.withMaxNumMutations(maxNumMutations)
                .withFailureMode(FailureMode.REPORT_FAILURES)
                );
```

But the problem with the code is, Dataflow code is retrying the entire batch because of '"ALREADY EXISTS"' Mutation. I can't use FailureMode.FAST_FAIL, because it stops the entire pipeline. I also tried to set the minimal MaxNumMutation to decrease the batch_size(basically to decrease the probability of 'already_exist' record in Mutation batch), but the overall performance hampers. So is there any way I can stop the retry mechanism for 'already exist' mutation record?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `InsertOrUpdate` mutation instead of `InsertMutation`. That will do exactly what you expect in this case; insert the row if it is not already there, and otherwise update it. In your case, the update will not do anything useful as no values should change, but it will stop your pipeline from breaking.

Example:

```java
    Mutation mutation = Mutation.newInsertOrUpdateBuilder("FOO")
        .set("ID")
        .to(1)
        .set("BAR")
        .to("BAZ")
        .build();
```

You can also see the previous in the [Spanner Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/java#write-data-with-mutations) .

Comment: That's what I already specified, I don't want to update the existing record. hope you got my point.

Comment: @miles212 Sorry, I missed that one. I thought you were running into this problem because your inserts were being retried, but if I understand you correctly, you have existing data in the table that was not inserted by the import, and that you don't want the import to update. That will be tricky then. Depending on the amount of data, it might be better to do the import to a separate, empty table, and then do the actual import later based on a query that filters out the already existing rows.

Comment: Basically Spanner automatically detects in case mutation already exist, I'm just looking for a solution to avoid the retry part to make the write throughput better.

Comment: The ability to mutate data in Spanner without updating already existing one is not implemented yet. However, there is feature request that meet your use case related to implementing ifexist method that can help workaround this issue. found the [feature request here](https://issuetracker.google.com/149385789).